# Node max size in cytoscape.js dagre layout?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

A major part of the project I'm building involves allowing users to create and edit DAGs fluidly. I'm using React, cytoscape.js, cytoscape edgehandles, and the dagre layout to accomplish this, and it's working pretty well, except for one annoying problem. When the graph only has a few nodes, the nodes are huge!

This is because I have fit set to true (the default) in the layout options. I need to keep this setting, because as the graphs grow I want them to zoom out to fit unless the user chooses to zoom in. I just don't want the first 1 - 4 nodes to be huge! Is there any way to define a max height/width for the nodes, or control the zoom level, or something, so that the nodes start off at a reasonable size and only start getting smaller when they have to?

Here's my layout:

```js
cy.layout({
      name: 'dagre',
      ranker: 'longest-path',
      padding: 15
    }).run();
```

And here's my style settings:

```js
const cyConfig = {
  elements: [],
  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'label': 'data(name)',
        'color': '#2C2029',
        'text-valign':'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-size': '25px',
        'font-family': 'Nixie One, cursive',
        'shape': 'roundrectangle',
        'background-color': 'mapData(inDegree, 1, 8, rgba(163, 154, 164), rgba(240, 146, 60))',
        'background-opacity': 'mapData(inDegree, 1, 8, .3, 1)',
        'border-color': 'transparent',
        'width': 'label',
        'height': 'label',
        'padding': '7px'
      }
    }, {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'target-arrow-fill': 'hollow',
        'target-arrow-color': '#2C2029',
        'width': '1px',
        'color': '#2C2029',
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always define your nodes like this:

```
style: [
            {
                selector: 'node',
                style: {
                    'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
                    'content': 'data(DisplayName)',
                    'height': 'data(faveHeight)',
                    'width': 'data(faveWidth)',
                    'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                    'line-color': '#a8eae5',
                    'font-family': 'Segoe UI', 
                    'font-size': '15px',
                }
            }
]
```

If you do so, you can check how many nodes you want to add to your cytoscape window and then define their width and height properties according to the number of nodes you want to add:

```
jsonNew.push({
        data: {
               id: yourId,
               parent: '',
               faveShape: 'yourShape',
               faveHeight: ((nodes.length > 7) ? nodes.length * 3 : nodes.length * 6),
               faveWidth: ((nodes.length > 7) ? nodes.length * 5 : nodes.length * 10),
               faveColor: '#ffffff'                                       
        },
        position: {
                    x: '',
                    y: ''
        },
        parents: '',
        group: 'nodes',
        removed: false,
        selected: false,
        selectable: true,
        locked: false,
        grabbable: true,
        classes: ''
});
```